# Weblogic server

Tags: weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

I have installed Weblogic server in my machine.While installing  i have configured domain with name MyDomain.At the end of configuration i checked start admin server.Server started successfully without issue.Next day I tried to start the server using C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse\User Projects\MyDomain\Start Admin Server for Weblogic Server Domain.lnk
When I Start that it is showing following Error: in Command Prompt

\Java\jre1.6.0_20\bin was unexpected at this time.
C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\MyDomain>
I have Installed oepe-wls-indigo-installer-11.1.1.8.0.201110211138-10.3.6-win

Please help me out on this issue

Answer (score 1):

u can start admin server from 
C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\MyDomain/servers/Adminserver/bin

Answer (score 0):

For Best Compatibility Install the bundle provided by oracle.